# Extracting lower Triangular matrix without considering diagonal element

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 5x5 matrix

```
A = 
   [0    0    0    0    1; 
    0.36 0    0    0    1; 
    0    0.25 0    0    1; 
    0.35 0    0    0    1;
    0    0    0.28 0    1];
```

I want to extract lower triangular elements of the matrix without considering the diagonal elements. Therefore, resulting matrix should be

```
C = [0.36 0 0.35 0 0.25 0 0 0 0.28 0]
```

Let me know how I can get this.

Comment: user962808 - I added the `matlab` tag. If this is incorrect, please remove it and add the tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use matlab `tril`, e.g.:

```
index = find(tril(ones(size(A)), -1));
C = A(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is Matlab, based on the format of the matrices.

If you  want the elements of the lower triangular portion in a row vector, you can do it with a loop (although I'm sure somebody will have a nifty vectorized approach):

```
C=[];
for n=1:size(A,1)
    C=[C,A(n+1:end,n)'];
end
```

The output is:

```
C =

  0.36  0.00  0.35  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.28  0.00
```

If instead you want the full 5x5 matrix, you would use the second argument of [`tril`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html):

```
C = tril(A,-1);
```

The output is:

```
C =

  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  0.36  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00
  0.35  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  0.00  0.00  0.28  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)-based approach:

```
C = A( bsxfun(@gt, (1:size(A,1)).', 1:size(A,2)) ).';
```